# How to update data on a market depth chart dynamically using Highcharts React library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, highcharts, react-highcharts

I manage to use HighchartsReact to plot some values from a grid to the Market Depth chart. The problem is that the array that has the values for the bids and asks updates continuously and currently I don't reflect this in my chart unless I refresh the page.

My code looks like this:

```
class MarketDepth extends React.Component<Props, State> {

   ...

    chart = null;

    state = {
        selectedBid: null,
        selectedAsk: null,
    };

    chartOptions = {
        chart: {
            type: 'area',
            zoomType: 'xy',
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Market Depth Chart',
            style: {
                color: '#FFFFFF',
                fontSize: '20px',
                lineHeight: '120%',
                fontWeight: '600',
            },
        },
        xAxis: {
            minPadding: 0,
            maxPadding: 0,
            crosshair: true,
            lineWidth: 0,
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            tickLength: 4,
            plotLines: [
                {
                    color: '#FFFFFF',
                    width: 1,
                    value: this.getAverageLine(), // set the actual price line value
                    label: {
                        text: 'Actual price',
                        rotation: 90,
                        align: 'right',
                        style: {
                            fonstStyle: 'italic',
                        },
                    },
                },
            ],
            title: {
                text: 'Price',
            },
        },
        yAxis: [
            {
                crosshair: true,
                lineWidth: 0,
                gridLineWidth: 0,

                title: {
                    text: 'Acc',
                },
                tickWidth: 1,
                tickLength: 5,
                tickPosition: 'inside',
                labels: {
                    align: 'left',
                    x: 8,
                },
            },
            {
                opposite: true,
                linkedTo: 0,
                lineWidth: 0,
                gridLineWidth: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Acc',
                },
                tickWidth: 1,
                tickLength: 5,
                tickPosition: 'inside',
                labels: {
                    align: 'right',
                    x: -8,
                },
            },
        ],
        legend: {
            enabled: false,
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: false,
                        lineWidthPlus: 0,
                    },
                    inactive: {
                        opacity: 1,
                    },
                },
                marker: { enabled: false },
                fillOpacity: 0.2,
                lineWidth: 1,
                step: 'center',
            },
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size=10px;">Price: {point.key}</span><br/>',
            valueDecimals: 2,
        },
        series: [
            {
                name: 'Bids',
                data: this.getBidOrders(),
                step: 'left',
            },
            {
                name: 'Asks',
                data: this.getAskOrders(),
                color: '#fc5857',
                step: 'right',
            },
        ],
    };

    getBidOrders() {
        ...
    }

    getAskOrders() {
        ... 
    }

   ...

   render() {

   return {
              <div id='chartContainer'>
                    <HighchartsReact
                        highcharts={Highcharts}
                        options={this.chartOptions}
                        allowChartUpdate
                    />
              </div>
          }

}
```

getAskOrders() and getBidOrder() methods return array that look like for example , could be larger or smaller depending on what needs to be ploted:

```
[
    [
        2179.25,
        30
    ],
    [
        2179,
        70
    ],
    [
        2178.75,
        113
    ],
    [
        2178.5,
        159
    ],
    [
        2178.25,
        206
    ]
]
```

Highcharts library : https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/depth-chart

Looks something like this: https://codepen.io/pen

Some things that I tried and might be worth looking :

- using  React `useState`hook to manage the state of the `chartOptions`.
- using `events` property in `chartOptions` to update the chart values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep the chart settings in a state and update it with new options, in your case passing new dates for the series:

```
updateSeries = () => {
  this.setState({ 
    chartOptions: {
      series: [
        { data: [Math.random() * 5, 2, 1]}
      ]
    }
  });
}
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hketvd?file=index.js

Comment: Thanks @Michael , yes that's a good Idea , using the state I can update that chart options.